# returning one value from a dict key with multiple values in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to return "runnerName" from the following dict:

```
{u'marketId': u'1.112422365',
 u'marketName': u'1m Mdn Stks',
 u'runners': [{u'handicap': 0.0,
               u'runnerName': u'La Napoule',
               u'selectionId': 8095372,
               u'sortPriority': 1},
              {u'handicap': 0.0,
               u'runnerName': u'Swivel',
               u'selectionId': 701378,
               u'sortPriority': 2},
              {u'handicap': 0.0,
               u'runnerName': u'Deanos Devil',
               u'selectionId': 8100420,
               u'sortPriority': 3},
              {u'handicap': 0.0,
               u'runnerName': u'Bishan Bedi',
               u'selectionId': 8084336,
               u'sortPriority': 4},
              {u'handicap': 0.0,
               u'runnerName': u'In Seine',
               u'selectionId': 8199415,
               u'sortPriority': 5},
              {u'handicap': 0.0,
               u'runnerName': u'Needs The Run',
               u'selectionId': 8199416,
               u'sortPriority': 6},
              {u'handicap': 0.0,
               u'runnerName': u'Appellez Baileys',
               u'selectionId': 8148513,
               u'sortPriority': 7},
              {u'handicap': 0.0,
               u'runnerName': u'Jessy Mae',
               u'selectionId': 7652545,
               u'sortPriority': 8},
              {u'handicap': 0.0,
               u'runnerName': u'Redy To Rumble',
               u'selectionId': 7366163,
               u'sortPriority': 9}]}
```

I have tried many different ways but cannot figure out how to access a value from a key with multiple values.

Comment: `[d['runnerName'] for d in a_dict['runners']]`

Comment: You might want to share with us the ways you tried. We would be happy to help you correct them :)

Comment: I tried something similar but kept, getting an error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str" accessing a keys value when there is only one I can do, having a few caught me out!

Comment: don't understand why people down vote when someone asks a question after spending a few hours trying to figure out the problem including searching this site. If I cannot figure it out, am I supposed to just give up or what?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can use list comprehension, like this, to retrieve the runner names from the dictionary of runners.

   ```
   print [runner["runnerName"] for runner in runners_dict["runners"]]
   ```
2. Or you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter), like this

   ```
   from operator import itemgetter
   print map(itemgetter("runnerName"), runners_dict["runners"])
   ```

**Output**

```
[u'La Napoule', u'Swivel', u'Deanos Devil', u'Bishan Bedi', u'In Seine',
 u'Needs The Run', u'Appellez Baileys', u'Jessy Mae', u'Redy To Rumble']
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I am doing something with the betfair api and am trying to modify  some example code to do what I want, I think they should get you to do the docs and examples as your method is a lot nicer than how they have done it! Thanks again.